# SQL SERVER Combining two columns as one column if a conditions happens

Tags: sql-server

i have a situation and couln't figure out for this time.Here's the question.

I have a table for accounting. Transactions are stored in this table.

```
Table Accounting

Plus Minus Flag

100  0     1
150  0     1
0    230   2
0    200   2
```

I want to combine these two columns as one column. It would be something like that.

New_Column

100
150
-230
-200

Comment: You mention a condition in your question. What's the condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Plus - Minus AS New_Column
FROM Accounting
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved the day.

Answer (score 0):

Cool answer from Ed :)

If you need to get the result based on Flag column though, here is the syntax

```
SELECT  CASE Flag 
            WHEN 1 THEN Plus 
            WHEN 2 THEN -Minus 
            ELSE NULL 
        END AS Total
FROM    Accounting
```